# Why isn't Navigating to Another Page in Google Appscript Working When Checking for Duplicate Data?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, redirect

I have a google appscript code which checks the form data and write it to the google sheet if there is no duplicate data available. I want the user to land to "successful page" if the data is successfully written to the google sheet and to another "message page" if the data is not written in the sheet. The function shows alert message but doesnot change url accordingly.

```
<script>
function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(goToSuccessPage).processForm(formObject); 
}

function goToSuccessPage(result) {
  alert(result);
  if(result){
    window.top.location.href = google.script.run.getUrl() + '?page=Link 1';
  } else {
    window.top.location.href = google.script.run.getUrl() + '?page=Link 2';
  } 
}
</script>

Code.gs 

for(var i=0; i< columnData.length; i++){
    if(columnData[i][0] === dataToCheck){ 
      dataExists = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(dataExists){
    return false;
    
  }else{
  ws.appendRow([
    new_date,
    formObject.issue_summary,
    formObject.issue_key,
    formObject.issue_duration,
    formObject.overall,
    formObject.irt,
    formObject.tir,
    formObject.sr,
    formObject.su,
    formObject.comment
  ])
  return true;
  }
```